# objective c change size of subview

Tags: objective-c, subview

I'm pretty new to this and I don't completely understand all of the inner workings of Objective-C, so I was hoping someone could help me out.

Essentially I have a Person class, where each person is represented by a group of objects (a button, label, and image view) that appear and disappear at certain times throughout the implementation. Occasionally, I want the person to move, and the best way I have figured out so far is to treat all three objects separately and animate them at the same time.

I figured there must be a better way to do this, and I am wondering if it is possible to create something like a "subview" (I don't know if this is the right word for it) and insert the button/label/imageView onto that and then animate the subview. I would imagine it would be something like:

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
person.view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
[self.view addSubview:person.view];
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes this is definitely possible! Is your Person class inherited from UIViewController? You can see this in your .h file where Person is defined.

Comment: I believe so. The .h file starts off (after importing) with @interface Person : UIViewController {

Comment: If Person inherits from UIViewController, than it's not really a good solution to add the view controller as a subview. Instead, go to interface builder and change the class of your view controller to "Person".

Comment: You need to show the code for the `Person` class. There's not enough information in the question to diagnose the problem. The general answer is, "Yes you can create a view that has a button, label and image view as subviews, and then move that view around, and the three subviews will move with it."

Answer (score 0):

OK so I'm afraid you need to change your design a bit. Apple work on an [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) architectural design which is really important to adhere to when it comes to making Apps.

What you've got here is a mixing between the model and view which is exactly what isn't supposed to happen with MVC.

Essentially you've got:

1) `Model` layer which is where you have all your data and objects for encapsulating information, just like your `Person` class.

2) `View` layer which is for controlling and defining UI elements of your apps like `UIView`, `UIImageView` e.t.c.

3) `Controller` layer which is the interface between `Model` and `View` layers. This include classes like `UIViewController` which manages a `UIView`.

In your situation you need a `UIView` into which you can put all the relevant UI (buttons, images) that tell the user about a person. Then you need a `Person` class. Probably a subclass of `NSObject` that defines the information for each `Person` in your app e.g. maybe a `UIImage` property that can be displayed in a `UIImageView`. And then a controller (I would recommend `UIViewController`) which would instantiate the relevant `Person` objects and then update the UI as required.

I'm not entirely sure what you want in terms of animation but you can look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) for information on how to animate views. And check out:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                 animations:^{
    // Cool animations here...
}];
```

I would get to grips with MVC and other key concepts before getting too snazzy though...